# PHP - Increment array after a certain count is reached

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a question regarding PHP arrays. Let me tell you my story.

I have a report called inventory offtake. The purpose of the report is to view how much average sales a product is selling everyday.

**Here is the computation:**

```
(beginning inventory quantity + delivery quantity - ending inventory quantity) / (datediff(ending inventory quantity date - beginning inventory quantity date)))
```

But it is a three week running inventory: please see the screenshot:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, i labeled the first result, then the second. I also included the result and next to it is the formula. If the screenshot is not clear for  you please ask me, so I can help you understand my complicated question.

Now here is my code:

```
$index = 0;

foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    $final_array[$key]['sales_group_code'] = $value['sales_group_code'];
    $final_array[$key]['sales_office_code'] = $value['sales_office_code'];
    $final_array[$key]['sales_district_code'] = $value['sales_district_code'];
    $final_array[$key]['customer_code'] = $value['customer_code'];
    $final_array[$key]['customer'] = $value['customer'];
    $final_array[$key]['week_no'] = $value['week_no'];
    $final_array[$key]['product'] = $value['product'];
    $final_array[$key]['delivery_quantity'] = $value['delivery_quantity'];
    $final_array[$key]['inventory_date'] = $value['inventory_date'];
    $final_array[$key]['inventory_quantity'] = $value['inventory_quantity'];
    $final_array[$key]['overall_count'] = $value['overall_count'];
    $inventory_array[] = $value['inventory_quantity'];
    $inventory_date_array[] = $value['inventory_date'];
    if ($previous_product == $value['product']) {
        $delivery_array[] = $value['delivery_quantity'];
        if ($row_ctr > 2) {
            $row_ctr = 0;
            $inventory_ctr++;
            array_shift($delivery_array);
        }

        $row_ctr++;
        $final_delivery_array = array_slice($delivery_array, 0, 3);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $index; $i++) {
            if (array_key_exists($i, $final_delivery_array)) {
                $total_delivery+= $final_delivery_array[$i];
                $date1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($inventory_date_array[$inventory_date_ctr])));
                $date2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['inventory_date'])));
                $diff = $date2->diff($date1)->days;
                if ($diff > 0) {
                    $offtake = ((($total_delivery + $inventory_array[$inventory_ctr]) - $value['inventory_quantity']) / $diff);
                }
                else {
                    $offtake = ((($total_delivery + $inventory_array[$inventory_ctr]) - $value['inventory_quantity']) / 1);
                }

                $final_array[$index]['days'] = $diff;
                $final_array[$index]['offtake'] = number_format((float)$offtake, 2, '.', '');
                $final_array[$index]['days_to_last'] = ($value['inventory_quantity'] / $offtake);
            }
        }

        $total_delivery = 0;
    }
    else {
        $final_array[$index]['days'] = 0;
        $previous_product = $value['product'];
        $final_array[$index]['offtake'] = 0;
        $final_array[$index]['days_to_last'] = 0;
        $total_delivery = 0;
    }

    $index++;
}
```

I would try to explain my code:

I store all the delivery and the inventory quantity in an array.

I create a row counter and count up  to 3. I count 3 because remember we have three weeks moving result.

If the row counter reaches 3, I will unset the first element of the delivery and inventory array.

Now I am fine with that. I can  do that. It is working fine.

**Update: Here is the result of  my code:**

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sales_group_code] => 01
            [sales_office_code] => 013
            [sales_district_code] => 1307
            [customer_code] => BUD001
            [customer] => 1307-873 PPCI-ANTIPOLO SAN JOSE POB
            [week_no] => 10
            [product] => ASSORTED CUPCAKES
            [delivery_quantity] => 13.00
            [inventory_date] => 2018-03-06
            [inventory_quantity] => 4.08
            [overall_count] => 144
            [days] => 0
            [offtake] => 0
            [days_to_last] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sales_group_code] => 01
            [sales_office_code] => 013
            [sales_district_code] => 1307
            [customer_code] => BUD001
            [customer] => 1307-873 PPCI-ANTIPOLO SAN JOSE POB
            [week_no] => 11
            [product] => ASSORTED CUPCAKES
            [delivery_quantity] => 11.00
            [inventory_date] => 2018-03-13
            [inventory_quantity] => 15.50
            [overall_count] => 144
            [days] => 7
            [offtake] => -0.06
            [days_to_last] => -258.33333333333
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sales_group_code] => 01
            [sales_office_code] => 013
            [sales_district_code] => 1307
            [customer_code] => BUD001
            [customer] => 1307-873 PPCI-ANTIPOLO SAN JOSE POB
            [week_no] => 12
            [product] => ASSORTED CUPCAKES
            [delivery_quantity] => 7.00
            [inventory_date] => 2018-03-18
            [inventory_quantity] => 5.17
            [overall_count] => 144
            [days] => 12
            [offtake] => 1.41
            [days_to_last] => 3.6688350088705
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sales_group_code] => 01
            [sales_office_code] => 013
            [sales_district_code] => 1307
            [customer_code] => BUD001
            [customer] => 1307-873 PPCI-ANTIPOLO SAN JOSE POB
            [week_no] => 14
            [product] => ASSORTED CUPCAKES
            [delivery_quantity] => 12.00
            [inventory_date] => 2018-04-01
            [inventory_quantity] => 5.25
            [overall_count] => 144
            [days] => 26
            [offtake] => 1.11
            [days_to_last] => 4.7346514047867
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [sales_group_code] => 01
            [sales_office_code] => 013
            [sales_district_code] => 1307
            [customer_code] => BUD001
            [customer] => 1307-873 PPCI-ANTIPOLO SAN JOSE POB
            [week_no] => 17
            [product] => ASSORTED CUPCAKES
            [delivery_quantity] => 9.00
            [inventory_date] => 2018-04-23
            [inventory_quantity] => 35.67
            [overall_count] => 144
            [days] => 48
            [offtake] => 0.16
            [days_to_last] => 218.66666666667
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [sales_group_code] => 01
            [sales_office_code] => 013
            [sales_district_code] => 1307
            [customer_code] => BUD001
            [customer] => 1307-873 PPCI-ANTIPOLO SAN JOSE POB
            [week_no] => 20
            [product] => ASSORTED CUPCAKES
            [delivery_quantity] => 3.00
            [inventory_date] => 2018-05-14
            [inventory_quantity] => 17.67
            [overall_count] => 144
            [days] => 69
            [offtake] => 0.37
            [days_to_last] => 47.202090592334
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [sales_group_code] => 01
            [sales_office_code] => 013
            [sales_district_code] => 1307
            [customer_code] => BUD001
            [customer] => 1307-873 PPCI-ANTIPOLO SAN JOSE POB
            [week_no] => 21
            [product] => ASSORTED CUPCAKES
            [delivery_quantity] => 9.00
            [inventory_date] => 2018-05-22
            [inventory_quantity] => 7.17
            [overall_count] => 144
            [days] => 77
            [offtake] => 0.47
            [days_to_last] => 15.196531791908
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [sales_group_code] => 01
            [sales_office_code] => 013
            [sales_district_code] => 1307
            [customer_code] => BUD001
            [customer] => 1307-873 PPCI-ANTIPOLO SAN JOSE POB
            [week_no] => 24
            [product] => ASSORTED CUPCAKES
            [delivery_quantity] => 7.00
            [inventory_date] => 2018-06-11
            [inventory_quantity] => 10.58
            [overall_count] => 144
            [days] => 97
            [offtake] => 0.19
            [days_to_last] => 55.204948897257
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [sales_group_code] => 01
            [sales_office_code] => 013
            [sales_district_code] => 1307
            [customer_code] => BUD001
            [customer] => 1307-873 PPCI-ANTIPOLO SAN JOSE POB
            [week_no] => 8
            [product] => BROWNIES
            [delivery_quantity] => 2.00
            [inventory_date] => 2018-02-21
            [inventory_quantity] => 4.33
            [overall_count] => 144
            [days] => 0
            [offtake] => 0
            [days_to_last] => 0
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [sales_group_code] => 01
            [sales_office_code] => 013
            [sales_district_code] => 1307
            [customer_code] => BUD001
            [customer] => 1307-873 PPCI-ANTIPOLO SAN JOSE POB
            [week_no] => 10
            [product] => BROWNIES
            [delivery_quantity] => 3.00
            [inventory_date] => 2018-03-06
            [inventory_quantity] => 2.33
            [overall_count] => 144
            [days] => 0
            [offtake] => 26.84
            [days_to_last] => 0.086810730253353
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [sales_group_code] => 01
            [sales_office_code] => 013
            [sales_district_code] => 1307
            [customer_code] => BUD001
            [customer] => 1307-873 PPCI-ANTIPOLO SAN JOSE POB
            [week_no] => 11
            [product] => BROWNIES
            [delivery_quantity] => 9.00
            [inventory_date] => 2018-03-13
            [inventory_quantity] => 3.92
            [overall_count] => 144
            [days] => 7
            [offtake] => 3.61
            [days_to_last] => 1.0867326732673
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [sales_group_code] => 01
            [sales_office_code] => 013
            [sales_district_code] => 1307
            [customer_code] => BUD001
            [customer] => 1307-873 PPCI-ANTIPOLO SAN JOSE POB
            [week_no] => 12
            [product] => BROWNIES
            [delivery_quantity] => 3.00
            [inventory_date] => 2018-03-18
            [inventory_quantity] => 12.67
            [overall_count] => 144
            [days] => 12
            [offtake] => 1.13
            [days_to_last] => 11.19587628866
        )
```

As you can see from the result of my code, the days element keeps growing. That should not be the case.

**Here is my problem:**

In  the formula provided, we have to get the date difference of the beginning inventory date quantity and the ending inventory quantity date.

Now, my problem occur when I have completed the three weeks running result. If I have already completed the three weeks running result, I have to move to the next row, right? that would be my next beginning inventory. But my problem i always get the beginning inventory date. Even though I already moved to the next three weeks.
So you would imagine the datedifference always grow, because it always start on the first row.

**Now my question,** how can I also move the inventory date along with the delivery quantity and the inventory quantity.

I hope I explained it well. Please if there are unclear parts please ask me, I will explain it to you. I have been solving this for a month now.

Thankyou so much for showing interest in my question. Hope you can guide me or at least lead me where to look.

Thankyou.

**UPDATE. I would include my ms sql query.**

```html
select c.SGrp as sales_group_code,
  c.SOffc as sales_office_code,
  c.SDst as  sales_district_code,
  a.customer_code,
  case
  when
  c.CustAlias != '' then c.CustAlias
  else c.CustNm end as customer,
  a.product,  
  b.delivery_week,
  b.delivery_quantity,
  a.inventory_date,
  a.inventory_week as week_no,
  a.inventory_quantity,

  overall_count = count(*) over()

from (select a.CustCode as customer_code,
    c.ProdNm as product,
    cast(a.DtRcv as date) as inventory_date,
    datepart(wk, a.DtRcv) as inventory_week,
      CAST(sum(CAST(b.Qty AS FLOAT)/ c.CaseDiv) AS decimal(18,2)) as inventory_quantity
  from BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_H as a

    inner join BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_D as b
    on a.TransCtr = b.TransCtr

    inner join BigEMasterData.dbo.tbl_Materials as c
    on b.Material = c.ExtMatGrp

    group by a.CustCode,
       c.ProdNm,
       cast(a.DtRcv as date),
       datepart(wk, a.DtRcv)) as a
  

  inner join (select a.Cust as customer_code,
       a.ProdNm as product,
       a.WkNum as delivery_week,
       sum(a.EQCaseQty) as delivery_quantity
     from BigESales.dbo.tbl_CurrentSales as a


     group by a.Cust,
        a.ProdNm,
        a.WkNum) as b
  on a.customer_code = b.customer_code
  and a.inventory_week = b.delivery_week
  and a.product = b.product

  inner join BigEMasterData.dbo.tbl_Customers as c
  on a.customer_code = c.CustCode


  inner join BigEUsers.dbo.user_role_area as d
  on c.SDst = d.area_id

  inner join BigEUsers.dbo.users as e
  on d.role_id = e.role_id

where ((datepart(wk, a.inventory_week) >= datepart(wk, @date_from) and datepart(wk, a.inventory_week) <= datepart(wk, @date_to))
 
 
or  isnull(@date_from,'')='' OR isnull(@date_to,'')='')

and  ((a.product= @product)
or  (isnull(@product, '') = ''))

and  ((REPLACE(REPLACE(a.customer_code, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')  = @customer_code)
or  (isnull(@customer_code, '') = ''))

and  (e.id = @user_id)

and  e.is_active = 1

and   b.delivery_quantity >= 0

order by a.customer_code,
         a.product,
   a.inventory_week
offset @start rows
fetch next @page_size rows only
```

Comment: i'm assuming the origin of data are from db? is this just from a simple select straight away? as an alternative, what i would do is to group first by item (meaning each nesting per item), then get the average for each in every 3 weeks.

Comment: @vSugumar that is how you get the total inventory. As you can  see from the screen shot, I added the last inventory, plus the delivery minus the latest inventory.

Comment: @Ghost, it's a simple select with joins. Do you mean I will do it in my select statement? Would it help to clear things if I also include my select statement? Thanks for taking time to answer my question

Comment: you could add the pertinent query inside the question, you could also add the tag mysql (if it is indeed mysql). if i understand correctly, the days should reset after t he third week, right? or third entry of a product, you could probably chunk it by threes two if you want, it will add another dimension, but at least easier to manage and then you can average it

Comment: by the way, your `$inventory_date_ctr` isn't declared anywhere (according to the code above), you could probably unset the last 3 inside `$inventory_date_array` so that the date gets reset. since `$diff` is based on `$date*` variables, in order to get the reset, you need to debug what you're getting in the current `$inventory_date_array[$inventory_date_ctr]` iteration, right now, its probably stuck on the beginning date thats why its always based on the first date

Comment: @Ghost, I have added the query to my question. I am using MSSQL. And yes you are right, the days should reset after the third week.

Comment: @Ghost, I apologize I didn't include it in my post. But I have declared all the variables and array. And I can't just unset the 3 weeks in the inventory date array because, remember we are moving one week after three weeks. Hope I explained it clearly.